# How can I add dll to the GAC?

Tags: .net-4.0, gac, gacutil

running `gacutil.exe /i ProjectX.Core.dll`, I got the message: `Assembly sucessfully added to te cache`, but I can't see this assembly in the `c:\windows\assembly` folder.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which `assembly` folder are you looking in?  With .NET 4, there are now two potential locations: `\Windows\assembly` and `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` (with all of the various sub-directories beneath them).

Comment: I'm using .net-4, what is the other folder?  Edit: right. it's in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` folder...

Comment: @stacker: The second one I mentioned.  For me, this is `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`.